# Use of AGPL software on server with closed-source software

Tags: licensing, gpl, agpl

I need to use some software under the AGPL to populate a database with some data. This software has a web interface, which I shall disable.

Then the data will be used "at arms length" with closed-source software by reading the database. I may also use some IPC, like datagram sockets to provide a bridge between the AGPL software and the other software. This closed sourced software will provide a web interface to the user.

Am I right that it is not breaking the AGPL to have this software as closed source? If I modify the AGPL software, am I able to hide these modifications, so long that the software doesn't provide any network interface to other users?

Answer (score 1):

The Gnu AGPLv3 differs from the GPL only in how it applies to a situation where (a) you modify the software and (b) network users can "interact" with the software. In that case you are required to distribute the source code.

[If this is not the licence version you had in mind, then please amend your question.]

This part of the licence does not have "distribute" or "merge" wording, and does not seek to include "covered" software under the ambit of source code distribution. Your closed source code is safe.

> Am I right that it is not breaking the AGPL to have this software as closed source? If I modify the AGPL software, am I able to hide these modifications, so long that the software doesn't provide any network interface to other users?

Yes, and nearly. You must ensure the modified software does not provide any public network `interaction` to avoid this term. That's broader than "interface".

Comment: OK thanks, from what you said it sounds like it should be OK. The AGPL program wont do any network interaction at all, unless it is to connect to a database server kept within the same organisation.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an "arm's length" connection, but let's say for the sake of this discussion that it is.

In order to not be considered a derived work, your software must not depend on this "arms length" relationship in order to function properly.  Is that true of your software?  If it is not true, then you've created a derived work, and your software falls under the AGPL's copyleft provisions.

You may also sidestep the AGPL by *not distributing*.  The copyleft provisions do not apply if the software is "for internal use only," and is not "conveyed" to others outside your organization.

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer, but can I ask how you derive this from the AGPL wording? Because when I read it, it sounds like what I said was correct.

Comment: What part are you confused about?

Comment: The only real difference between the GPL and AGPL is clause 13.

Comment: Clause 13 only talks about modified versions of the program, and specifically only gives the requirement to provide sources to "all users interacting with it remotely through a computer network (if your version supports such interaction)"

Comment: @MattMitchell: That's an additional conveyance restriction imposed by the AGPL, not the only restriction.  It essentially means that you can't stand up a public website and claim that you are not distributing.

Comment: If I use a separate program to access the database and give a web interface, surely that doesn't come under a AGPL "modified program", as it's a separate piece of software: "The Program" refers to any copyrightable work licensed under this
License.

Comment: I did a diff on the AGPL and GPL and couldn't see any other major differences.

Comment: Ah, but that's not what you claimed in your question. You claimed that the database that you are connecting to is an integral part of an AGPL application.

Comment: The database is populated by the AGPL application, but the database software is not part of the AGPL application. The AGPL application simply connects to a mysql database.

Comment: And that MySQL database can be *any* database?  It doesn't have a schema that is specific to the AGPL application?

Comment: It does have a schema that is given in the AGPL application.

Comment: Then I would say that a reasonable person would view that database as an integral part of the AGPL application.  It's probably even distributed with the application.  Ergo, it falls under the AGPL, and so does your application that is connecting to it if you're standing up a public web page or other public API.

Comment: That said, you got me thinking about database schemas in general.  They're not code, so they could be considered an "output" of the application.  Whether that's "arm's length communication" or not is still debatable; I argue that it is not.  The counterexample would be, say, communicating with a library via a JSON call, where JSON is the primary mode of communication with the library.  Would that be considered "arms-length?"  Not necessarily.

Comment: Also, you still haven't demonstrated that your application will work without knowledge of the database schema that is part of this other program.  If your application won't work without it, I'm still not sure that you can claim that it is not a derivative work.

Comment: Well the software would not contain the "CREATE TABLE" queries, but would of-course reference the tables and the table fields in other queries. I have my doubts that the table and field names even come under copyright protection.

Comment: You could always ask the FSF, and see what they think.  I'm pretty sure that every field and field name and table relationship that I've written into a program's database schema falls under the same copyright protection as the program itself.  If that weren't the case, you might as well eliminate software interfaces, method names, XML files and variable declarations from copyright protection as well.

Comment: @MattMitchell: The basic question is: *Must* the database be populated by the AGPL program, or is it sufficient for your code that somehow a database exists with the right data (that could have been produced by another program without knowledge of the AGPL one)? In the first case, it is likely that the FSF will regard your program as a derived work. In the second you are definitely working at arms length.

Comment: the "I may also use some IPC, like datagram sockets to provide a bridge between the AGPL software and the other software. This closed sourced software will provide a web interface to the user." part seems more directly a breach of the license to me

Comment: @Bart van Ingen Schenau: In any case it should be possible to replicate the database functionality of the AGPL software with another program, but such an alternative does not exist.